# How to manually change feature values of decision trees in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In scikit-learn, if I have a decision tree pulled from

```
RandomForestClassifer().estimators_
```

Is there a way I can manually change some of the features? I can iterate through them using

```
for estimator in rfc.estimators_:
    for feature in estimator.tree_.feature:
```

but I would like to manually change the feature in this case. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly then you want to changes the parameters of the decision trees inside the random forest ? I am not exactly sure why you would want to do that.

I will break the solution into two parts

**First we will try to change the parameters of a decision tree**

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)

iris = load_iris()

clf.fit(iris.data,iris.target)
#DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
#       max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
#        min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
#        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
#        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=0,
#        splitter='best')

#Now extract the parameters
parameters_dt = clf.get_params()

#Now change the parameter you want
parameters_dt['max_depth'] = 3

#Now create a new classifier
new_clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(**parameters_dt)
#DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=2,
#        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
#        min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
#        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
#        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=0,
#        splitter='best')
```

**Now lets get back to Random Forest**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                        n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                       random_state=0, shuffle=False)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)

clf.fit(X, y)

clf_list = clf.estimators_
for idx in range(0,len(clf_list)):
    #Get the current Decision Tree in Random Forest
    estimator = clf_list[idx]

    #Get the params
    temp_params = estimator.get_params()

    #Change the params you want
    temp_params['max_depth'] = 3

    #Create a new decision tree
    temp_decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(**temp_params)

    #Remove the old decision tree
    clf.estimators_.pop(idx)

    #Then insert the new decision tree at the current position
    clf.estimators_.insert(idx, temp_decision_tree)
```

**Note**: This might not have the effect that you want. I mean it might not result in the exact classifier that you want.

Comment: This is very close to what I want, thank you. Instead of creating a new tree with new parameters, my aim is to simply change a node in the decision tree. The reason for this is the nodes in the tree I am working with are (x,y,z) coordinates with values associated as the decision points. I want to see that if I move the coordinate in some n-ball, how much will the decision tree change. Overall, I'd like to be able to manually edit a node of an already built Decision Tree

Comment: In your case you can't actually edit a node to see the changes. Whatever node parameter that you change will reflect throughout the tree and hence it won't make any difference. For. e.g. you can't have certain nodes to have property `max_depth` as 2 and other nodes with `max_depth` as 3. These parameters remain the same throughout

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to have different max_depth properties, no. What I want to do is to change the specific "question" that a node is asking. If a node on a decision tree says "if X > 5, then go left in the tree" I want to change the X to some Y

Comment: The decision is based on an entropy threshold or min. Threshold value that is fixed throughout the tree. Thats not possible. My point here is, any rule or property you set, is fixed throughout the tree.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you. Is it possible to manually build a Decision Tree then? I.e. node by node? I'm assuming no.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you would have to implement your own decision tree to do the manual changing of nodes that you want. :)

Comment: I think that would be fine, is there documentation for building a Decision Tree node by node? Sorry if this is a trivial question, I just haven't found any.

Comment: From my experiences, I've learned that the original decision tree code is proprietary so it was not released. Only the pseudocode is available. You would need to write your own decision tree code and implement a function to build a tree node by node.